# Prove that $\text{Frac}(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I'm trying to prove that the field of fractions for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$.
I know exactly how to go about this problem, but I'm just confused as to how to define the function.
I tried the following:
"Define a function $\phi: \text{Frac}(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]) \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ by $\phi(\frac{p+r\sqrt{d}}{s+t\sqrt{d}})=\frac{p}{s}+\frac{r}{t}\sqrt{d}$."
This function gave me some pretty ugly irreducible computations in terms of proving that it respected addition.
Is there another function I should be using?

Comment: Hint: multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator. What happens?

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing! Thank you. Does the function itself look fine?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You should map to what the conjugation map sends to. Otherwise, proving bijectivity will be a nightmare. (actually, not even sure whether your map is bijective)

Comment: Like how you would compute $\dfrac1{1-\sqrt2}$

Comment: I found that elements in $\text{Frac}(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$ are of the form $\frac{p+r\sqrt{d}}{s+t\sqrt{d}}=\frac{(p+r\sqrt{d})(s-t\sqrt{d})}{(s+t\sqrt{d})(s-t\sqrt{d})}=\frac{ps+rs\sqrt{d}-rt\sqrt{d}-rtd}{s^2-dt^2}=\frac{(ps-rtd)+(rs-rt)\sqrt{d}}{s^2-dt^2}$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: I think you meant $-pt\sqrt d$, not $-rt\sqrt d$

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. How should I define a function from here?

Comment: You have basically got it, a map to something of the form $a+b\sqrt d$, where $a,b\in\mathbb Q$

Comment: I'm still getting really ugly computations when I use this new function. Is that okay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another take.

The field of fractions for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is the smallest subfield $K$ of $\mathbb C$ that contains $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$.

Now $\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ implies $\mathbb Q \subseteq K$ and so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) \subseteq K$.

Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is a field containing $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, it must contain $K$, that is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) \supseteq K$.

Therefore, $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$.

Comment: So we don't have to explicitly state an isomorphism? Your solution makes perfect sense to me, I just want to make sure.

Comment: No, unless you've been asked to explicitly give an isomorphism.

Comment: The problem just states exactly what was in the title, so I think this should be fine. Thanks for your help!