# Show that $\text{Frac}(\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2}))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

> Show that $\text{Frac}(\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2}))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Here $\text{Frac}(\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2}))$ is the fiel of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2})$.

I already proved that $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2})$ is an integral domain. Thus we can construct its field of fracions $F$. Define $\alpha:F\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ via $$\alpha([a+b\sqrt{2},c+d\sqrt{2}])=(a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2})^{-1}=\frac{ac-2bd}{c^2-2d^2}+\frac{bc-ad}{c^2-2d^2}\sqrt{2}$$ It's easy to see check that $\alpha $ is a homomorphism. Now since $\text{Ker}(\alpha)$ is an ideal of $F$, we have that $\text{Ker}(\alpha)=\{0\}$ or $F$. But $\alpha([1,1])=1\neq 0$. Thus $\text{Ker}(\alpha)=\{0\}$, and hence $\alpha$ is one-to-one.

How can I prove that $\alpha$ is onto?

I know that $\alpha(F)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, but I don't see clear that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subseteq \alpha(F) $. In [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3550033/790670) answer they give the double inclusion, but I can't quite understand why. If you could extend this argument or tell me how with what I have done I can show that $\alpha$ is onto, I would appreciate it

Comment: Set $d=0$ should help.

Comment: $\alpha(F)$ is a field which contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and the element $\sqrt{2}$. So by definition it must contain $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: To add on to Mark, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ is defined to be the minimal field containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt2$. (i.e., the intersection of all fields $K\supseteq\mathbb Q$ with $\sqrt2\in K$.)

Comment: You should write $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ instead, the ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $\sqrt{2}$.